# Handling browser back button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to handle the browser back button in javascript. I have implemented the tabs functionality in JS. So I want the user to return to the exact time from where they navigated to another page.

I can keep the tab # in some hidden input field. and check with the same in javascript.

But how do I make sure that a function gets called in javascript when the user hits the back button. some help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's the other way around. When you load all content through hxr, the back button doesn't behave as the user expects.

Comment: I think amit means that he has tabs created in JS (not in browser). So navigating away is probably unwanted. But this is just a guess, question is unclear.

Comment: What he wants is: When user pushes tha browser's navigation buttons the change of tabs should be recognized. Like user goes to Tab 1, 2 and 3, user pushes back button, user lands in tab 2 instead of the previous page.

Comment: absolutly, my comment was a response to a deleted one (about history.go(-1))

Comment: Sebastian Wramba has the clear idea. I want to do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.html#streaming_tab) (from jQuery tools) does exactly what you want.

HTML:

```
<!-- tabs title --> 
<ul id="flowtabs"> 
    <li><a id="t1" href="#player_tab">The Player</a></li> 
    <li><a id="t2" href="#plugins_tab">Plugins</a></li> 
    <li><a id="t3" href="#streaming_tab">Streaming</a></li> 
</ul> 

<!-- tabs content --> 
<div id="flowpanes"> 
    <div>tab1 html here</div> 
    <div>tab2 html here</div> 
    <div>tab3 html here</div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
    $("#flowtabs").tabs("#flowpanes > div", { history: true });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i like this plugin. but the thing is the whole tab functionality is already put in place and i cannot tinker around with the way things are structured.

Comment: You can still study how `jQuery tools` makes it: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/tree/master/src/tabs

Answer (score 0):

how about `history.go(-1)` ?

```
$(function(){ 

$("#myLink").click(function(){ 
history.go(-1);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read [this article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/10/26/ajax-handling-bookmarks-and-back-button.html?page=1).

Basically, it's based on the dhtmlhistory object, and it change the url in the browser.